# No module named '_swigfaiss' in Windows

Tags: python, swig

I have an existing **linux** python project that uses **faiss**.

The project has the following swigfaiss wrapper as detailed here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/master/INSTALL.md

[image]

And the python source code includes faiss as follows:

```
import faiss
```

When I run it in windows (in Visual Studio 2019) I get the error:

**No module named '_swigfaiss'**

I think I need to convert the program to run on Windows as the **_swigfaiss.so** is obviously built for Linux.

I have downloaded and built the Windows version of faiss using Visual Studio here: https://github.com/bitsun/faiss-windows.  This produces a library file **faissd.lib**

How can I use this library file in my python program?

Or get the original to work on Windows?

Comment: It will probably be much easier to just run in something Linux-like such as WSL, but if you don't want to do that, you'd have to also build the SWIG wrapper on Windows against the faissd.lib library.

Comment: WSL is not an option I can run with unfortunately.

Comment: Somewhere it should build a .dll file. That file needs to be renamed to .pyd for Windows for `import` to just work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import faiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250476/unable-to-import-faiss)